# Auspicious date for Griha Pravesh - before Holi or after Holi?

Tags: astrology, festivals, customs, scripture, vastu-shastra

We are buying a new house and planning for a *Griha Pravesh* pooja on 2nd march, but we are getting conflicting opinions from friends and families. Some people say that we should do it after Holi, and some say that it's ok to do it before Holi.

Short of paying a pundit for advice (which I would still doubt), is there a reference available to guide me whether it's auspicious to do Griha Pravesh before Holi or not?

Comment: @sv. Is the OP asking about dates generally after or before holi or march 2nd 2015? It is unclear. If latter is correct, I think it is opinion based.

Comment: @SreeCharan IMO, although it sounds like a personal advice question, the "before Holi or after Holi" part can be answered independently. Maybe the answer is "it doesn't matter if a muhūrta is good."

Comment: It was meant for 2015

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [Holi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holi) is celebrated on the **Phalguna Purnima** day.

Here i'm referring to the book ["Essence of Dharma Sindhu"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) which quotes from Scriptures like Matsya Purana and others while discussing Vastu Prakarana:

> **Vaastu Prakarana:**
>
> Vaishaakhey **Phalgune** Poushey Shraaaney Maargasirshakey, Grihaarambha
>   Prave shoustah stambhocchraayas chashasyatey||
>
> Grihaarambha, Stambhoddhaarana and **Griha Pravesha are best performed
>   in the months of** Vaishakha, **Phalguna**, Pousha, Shraavana, and
>   Margasirsha. Jyeshtha, Kartika Maagha Months are also beneficient as
>   per Narada Vachana. A Parna Griha or a grass house could be
>   constructed without any month or time. But a house in which one likes
>   to reside himself or the Main House should not be constructed in
>   Pushya Maasa.....

**So,to start with,  Phalguna month is one of the best months to do a Griha Pravesha in.**

Hence,apparently,one can do Griha Pravesha on any of the days of Phalguna irrespective of whether that day comes before or after Holi.

But having said that, there are other factors as well ,like Tithi-Nakshtra-Yogas etc,that are also  to be considered with due importance.

> Vaastu Shanti has to be performed only in the day time. There is an
>   opinion that Griha Pravesha might be done in the nights also, in
>   which case, this Shanti function might as well be done at the same
>   Dina Maasaadi of Grihaarambha. The Shubha Kaala for Griha Pravesha
>   is stated to be in Maagha,Ashviyuja Jyeshtha Maasaas; Mridu-Dhruva
>   Nashatras are the most suitable, while Kshipra-Chara Nakshatras are o
>   f medium value. Teekshna-Ugra-Mishra Nakshatras are not good. If the
>   Karta’s Janma Lagna is not in the Eighth position,the Graha Pravesha
>   Lagna is commended.

I have posted the above passage only to emphasize the fact that a whole lot of rules and conditions are needed to be checked upon before planning a Griha Pravesha.And you should always consult a Pundit for that because all the rules are not known to us.